# Retrieving intrinsic matrix from two stereo depth sensor that resulted in a single depth image

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction, vision, camera-intrinsics, depth-camera

I have one stereo camera that outputs the depth and RGB images. I have retrieved the distortion and camera matrix using the checkered board(intrinsic matrix for RGB camera).
However, in the above discussion it seems like we need the **depth sensor intrinsic matrix** too to align RGB and depth image together.
I have worked with retrieving RGB camera matrix but not the depth sensor when my two depth sensors are providing me with one depth image.
I would like to have some insights regarding the above question, as I am stuck with how do I proceed further.